# Adding a css ::before to an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I know this sounds silly and you're going to ask why I'm just not using css, I assure you I have a reason. I'm building an app that is configurable to the user and part of that is changing the background color. Changing the background color is no problem however I have one spot where I'm gently fading an image into the background using a css shadow on a ::before.

My css kind of looks like this

```
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px rgba(230,235,242,0.98);
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px rgba(230,235,242,0.98);
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px rgba(230,235,242,0.98);
```

And to try and covert it to jQuery I tried something like this

```
$('.titleImage .shadow::before').css('-webkit-box-shadow', "inset 0px 0px 90px 50px" + Props['BackgroundColor']);
```

But it doesn't want to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://pankajparashar.com/posts/modify-pseudo-elements-css/

Comment: because css is loaded with page before js, they are stored in document object. If your js can't work, stylesheets are loaded yet. You need inject the loaded stylesheet value. Dump your document.styleSheets and you'll see all stylesheets of document can you change via inject

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can't target pseudo elements (don't ask for a workaround, there isn't one), but you can toggle a class on an element that adds/removes/modifies pseudo elements.

```js
$('div').on('click',function(){ $(this).toggleClass('pseudo'); });
```

```css
div:before {
  content:"Hi";
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }

div.pseudo:before { border-width: 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I need to be able to change the color of the shadow though, that's my issue. Not turning it off and on.

Comment: @zazvorniki - it's just CSS, make it do whatever you want. The point is, you have to use a class and **can't modify the pseudo element with jQuery directly**.

Comment: Unfortunately, @zazvorniki, your issue doesn't enable jQuery, or even JavaScript, to become able to achieve the impossible.

Comment: @DavidThomas, no need to be rude. I'm trying to figure out a workaround to something that my boss adamantly wants.

Comment: @zazvorniki - we're not being rude, we're telling you that this is the way to accomplish what you want to do. There's no point in looking for a workaround, because one doesn't exist. JavaScript cannot access pseudo elements.

Comment: @Adam "JavaScript cannot access pseudo elements." really ? what about document object?

Comment: @daremachine - *JavaScript cannot access pseudo elements* at a DOM level to modify its properties... so, yeah really!

Comment: @LcSalazar you are correct. You sent all sentence. But you can remove and add new. It is not about access but access to modify i thought

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo selector can not select using jquery. Work around is using inline css instead like below:

```
$('.titleImage .shadow').append('<style> .titleImage .shadow::before {-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px rgba(230,235,242,0.98); -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px rgba(230,235,242,0.98);box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px rgba(230,235,242,0.98);}</style>');
```

You can remove that style as well if needed

Comment: I wonder how is the maintenance quality of this approach.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Add an element to the dom, like:

```
<style id="mySpecialStyles"></style>
```

And a function like:

```
function changeColor(newColor){
    $('#mySpecialStyles').text(
        '.titleImage .shadow::before{' + 
        '-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px '+ newColor +';' +   
        'box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 90px 50px '+ newColor +';}'
    )    
}

// called like
changeColor('#000000');
```

That keeps it to a single style tag that you alter.

Check out [this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/1vcnvavd/).

HTH